# Eclipse CDT: Index / apply syntax highlighting with .icc files

Tags: indexing, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt

As of now, Eclipse CDT does not index [`.icc` files (inline functions)](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/c%2B%2B.rules/chap4.html), nor it applies syntax highlighting.

**How can I achieve this?**

I tried *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *General* -> *Content Types* -> *Text* -> *C Source Files* -> *C++ Source File* -> *File associations* -> *Add* -> **.icc* -> *Apply and close*,
but it didn't help.

**Related**:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/333251/how-to-change-default-file-extension-eclipse-uses-for-source-code-files
2. https://sahipro.com/docs/faq/eclipse-integration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was the right thing to do.
Now I have `.icc` files indexed and part of the code navigation.

I was only missing some additional actions.
I am not sure which of these I tried before checking that `.icc` files were indexed and which I did not.
And I am not sure which are actually needed.
Just in case, use all of them.

1. Right click on a project -> *Index* -> *Rebuild*.
2. For projects having other *Project references*, rebuild the index first for the reference, then for current the project.
3. Restart Eclipse (likely not needed).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Eclipse CDT 2019-03:

1. Open a project that contains a .icc file and which successfully has C++ indexing working - other than for the .icc file
2. Open a file that calls a function in the .icc file
3. Click on a function that references a member of the .icc and hit F3
4. As above: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> C Source Files -> C++ Source File -> File associations -> Add -> *.icc -> Apply and close
5. Close the tab containing the .icc file
6. Repeat step 3 again

I did not try any other approaches to know if the steps can be simplified.